# Loop through an array of dates and mark 10 year ranges using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timeline

I have an array of years:

```
$years = [1952,1954,1961,1962,1965,1982,1984,1984,1984,1985,1986,1986,1987,1988,1990,1991,1991,1993,1995]
```

I'm creating a timeline and my timeline uses 10 years of ranges, so it looks like this:

```
       1950      1960      1970      1980
.........|.........|.........|.........|.........
```

With the help of the jQuery each function i loop through these years and i display them on the timeline by creating a div and i position them using the left css attribute (1 year is 22px):

```
$.each(years, function(key, value) { 
    var event = $('<div>').addClass('event');
    var posX = value*21;

    event = event.html(value).css('left',posX+'px');

    $('#timeline').append(event);
});
```

So far so good, but us you can see i have lots of years and i can't display them correctly.

If in a **10 year range** theres **more than 3** events, i want to display a button instead of the event div and when i click on it i can use a popup to show the rest of the events.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It would be easier if your data was formatted better, each year should be unique, and the events should be inside the year. Eg: `{1952: ['event'], 1984: ['event1', 'event2']}`

Comment: It looks like that, i just simplified it for the question

Comment: In that case, update the code to reflect the _actual_ data you're using. In order to help you with a solution that works for you, we'll need to see the actual structure you're using.

Comment: Oh ok, i see what you mean. Its coming from the server and i can't change that, so i have to make it work with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to work with years in their associated decades.  I would create a `decades` array and populate it like the following:

```
var $years = [1952,1954,1961,1962,1965,1982,1984,1984,1984,1985,1986,1986,1987,1988,1990,1991,1991,1993,1995];

var decades = [];
for(var i=0; i<$years.length; i++)
{
    var year = $years[i];
    var decade = (Math.floor(year / 10) * 10);
    if(!decades[decade])
        decades[decade] = [];
    decades[decade].push(year);
}

for(decade in decades){
    var years = decades[decade];
    // decade will be 1950, 1960, 1980, etc.
    // years will be an array of years within that decade

    if(years.length > 3) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
​
```